# ffplay crashed on HLS streaming with toggled -an and -vn options

Tags: video, ffmpeg, performance-testing

When I try to start silent(without audio and video streams) playing of HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) by typing

```
ffplay -an -vn -i "http://localhost:8080/video/find?startTime=
1376716800000&endTime=1376717400000
```

I get the next error message on my console:

```
ffplay version N-67063-g282c935 Copyright (coffee) 2003-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 20 2014 22:10:09 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 10.100 / 54. 10.100
  libavcodec     56.  8.102 / 56.  8.102
  libavformat    56.  9.101 / 56.  9.101
  libavdevice    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://localhost:8080/video/find?startTime=137671
6800000&endTime=1376717400000':
  Duration: 00:01:50.12, start: 1.418722, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 320x240 [
SAR 19:32 DAR 19:24], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 14
7 kb/s
Failed to open file 'http://localhost:8080/video/find?startTime=1376716800000&en
dTime=1376717400000' or configure filtergraph
```

Is this bug or feature that ffplay can't playing video without audio/video stream? I need to run ffplay programmatically from my java test application to view loadout of my service.

P.S: I also tried adding the options "-nodisp -an", but that provided the same result as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but for Multicast

```
ln -s /dev/null file
ffmpeg -dn -i udp://@224.224.224.224:1234 -f null file
```

That works for me and hope somebody find it's helpful.